# how to achieve full calendar in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

[image]

I want this full calendar in ionic 2 like above one.

I installed the  cordova calendaree plugin for ionic 2

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-calendar
```

this code also

html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime min={{currentDate}}  displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="chosenDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

ts.file

```
export class InviteDates {
public currentDate: String;
public chosenDate: String;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private platform:Platform) {
  this.currentDate = (new Date()).toISOString();
  this.chosenDate = this.currentDate;
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? what is the question?

Comment: i want full calendar like the above image like...

Comment: @n00b i am not getting errors but i am getting ionic scroll calender like this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#datetime

Answer (score 1):

Calendar in  Ionic 2 can be achieved using "**ionic2-calendar**"

```
npm install ionic2-calendar --save
```

Then, import the calendar in your app.module.ts using,

```
import { NgCalendarModule } from 'ionic2-calendar';
```

Create Random events using the following code,

```
    var events = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
        var date = new Date();
        var eventType = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        var startDay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) - 45;
        var endDay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + startDay;
        var startTime;
        var endTime;
        if (eventType === 0) {
            startTime = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate() + startDay));
            if (endDay === startDay) {
                endDay += 1;
            }
            endTime = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate() + endDay));
            events.push({
                title: 'All Day - ' + i,
                startTime: startTime,
                endTime: endTime,
                allDay: true
            });
        } else {
            var startMinute = Math.floor(Math.random() * 24 * 60);
            var endMinute = Math.floor(Math.random() * 180) + startMinute;
            startTime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + startDay, 0, date.getMinutes() + startMinute);
            endTime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + endDay, 0, date.getMinutes() + endMinute);
            events.push({
                title: 'Event - ' + i,
                startTime: startTime,
                endTime: endTime,
                allDay: false
            });
        }
    }
    return events;
```

For Video reference have a look at [YouTube](https://youtu.be/UVOV2hTkkvE)

For Implementation of Calendar with Events have a look at [CodeExpertz](http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/mobile/ionic-2-calendar)

[image]